# Changing object in Activity from a Class

Tags: java, android

I have an `Activity` that has **two objects** of different classes.

I have a **CanvasLayout** class that needs to change the activity's objects upon certain conditions.

How do I do this?

**CurrentlyCountingActivity**

```
public class CurrentlyCountingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CanvasLayout canvasLayout;

    //I want to call one of the carCommands and 
    //pathCoordinates functions from canvasLayout
    CarCommands carCommands;
    PathCoordinates pathCoordinates;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        canvasLayout = new CanvasLayout(this);
        setContentView(canvasLayout);
        carCommands = new CarCommands();

        //because I don't want the car to be moving initially
        carCommands.setAbsoluteSpeed(0, 0);
    }

    //Other functions dealing with Path coordinates
}
```

**CanvasLayout class**

```
public class CanvasLayout extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    ... initializations here

    @Override
    public void run() {

        prepBrush();

        while(canDraw) {
            ..other irrelevant code

            motionPoint();

            ...more code


            if((pointX == INITIAL_X) && (pointY == INITIAL_Y)) {
                canDraw = false;
                //I would like to have something like 
                //carCommands.setAbsoluteSpeed(0, 0); here
            }
        }
    }


   private void motionPoint() {
       //I want to call pathCoordinates of Activity in CanvasLayout
       pathCoordinates.trackPathCoordinates();
       pointX = pathCoordinates.getX();
       pointY = pathCoordinates.getY();

   }

}
```

Comment: You can make the object as static so that you can acess it from the class directly and can change the value, and as it is static, it will have only one memory allocation throught the app, so there will not be multiple instances

Comment: using interface is the way to go

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki static means that every instance of the activity class shares the same object. This is not correct in most situations where you only do it for ease of access.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Interface](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm).

**SurfaceView**

```
private OnCanvasListener onCanvasListener;
public class CanvasLayout extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

  public interface OnCanvasListener{

    public void doSomething();
   }

   public CanvasLayout(Context this){
onCanvasListener = (OnCanvasListener)this;
   }


 @Override
    public void run() {

        prepBrush();

        while(canDraw) {
            ..other irrelevant code

            motionPoint();

            ...more code


            if((pointX == INITIAL_X) && (pointY == INITIAL_Y)) {
                canDraw = false;
                //I would like to have something like 
                //carCommands.setAbsoluteSpeed(0, 0); here
                 onCanvasListener.doSomething(); // invoke interface method

            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Implement interface in activity**

```
public class CurrentlyCountingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnCanvasListener  {

    CanvasLayout canvasLayout;

    //I want to call one of the carCommands and 
    //pathCoordinates functions from canvasLayout
    CarCommands carCommands;
    PathCoordinates pathCoordinates;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        canvasLayout = new CanvasLayout(this);
        setContentView(canvasLayout);
        carCommands = new CarCommands();

        //because I don't want the car to be moving initially
        carCommands.setAbsoluteSpeed(0, 0);
    }

    //Other functions dealing with Path coordinates

  @Override
public void doSomething(){

// implement your logic here.
}

}
```

*Sorry for any typo . hope this will help.*

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to provide access to the CarCommands object:

1. Create a constructor in CanvasLayout which takes a CarCommands object.
2. Create a setter method in CanvasLayout which takes a CarCommands object.
3. Create the CarCommands object in CanvasLayout.
4. Add methods to the activity class which allow access to the CarCommands object and add a constructor to CanvasLayout that accepts a CurrentlyCountingActivity.

I am sure there are other options as well. Which one you choose depends heavily on other factors in the design of your code. I learn towards #3. Does the activity really need the CarCommands?

I suggest that you continue to learn about object oriented principles. Only experience will help you judge the tradeoffs for design decisions such as this.

Comment: But I need the same set of carCommands in both, so it doesn't make sense to create another carCommands object in CanvasLayout.

Comment: @Kek I did not say create **another** CarCommands object. I am saying create it in CanvasLayout **instead**. Does the activity really need access to the CarCommands object? If so, how come?

Comment: Yeah, it does. It's actually responsible for giving most of the car commands, because it is supposed to be running the car and detecting obstacles, whereas the canvas layout is just for drawing the path of the car, and when the car comes back to its original position, telling the car to stop.

Comment: @Kek That makes sense. Then either #1 or #4 are good solutions for you.